# Problems signing Android application with keystore

Tags: android, google-maps

So here's the thing. I have downloaded an example project of GoogleMaps for Android. I haven't changed it at all. For some reason I couldn't download Google API version 9, a friend sent me his SKD file. I have searched for MD5 fingerprint before and after i took his SDK file and it was the same both times. I have then obtaine Maps API key from Google Website, inserted it into .xml layout file of that project and then wanted to export Android application. I've browsed for my debug.keystore file, inserted password: android, clicked next, selected alias: androiddebugkey and again inserted password android, selected random destination APK file clicked finish. The export wizard then sends a warning saying Failed to export application. Can anyone help me? It worked for my friend just fine. Should i copy his .android file too?

Answer (score 1):

you have taken your friends SDK but did you copy that SDK 9 in your SDK'S addon folder. If not then please copy and paste SDK 9 which you take from your friend. Then try to take MAP key again.

One more as per my knowledge you will never get same MD5 key as your friend got. both should be different. as debug.keystore are different.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have copied the entire Android SDK file, including add-ons and everything, file was arround 3gb large. The MD5 key was different than my friends, so that's ok. thx for reply